# Determine if an element is a jQueryUI Widget

Tags: jquery-ui, widget

I have written a jquery-ui widget using the Widget Factory...

I need to be able to determine in code whether the element is already a widget or not...

My investmentGrid widget is created on #container with

```
 $('#container').investmentGrid()
```

I need to be able to determine elsewhere in the code if $('#container') is already an investmentGrid

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can query the element's `jQuery.data()` function, like so:

```
if ($('#container').data('investmentGrid')) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could try the pseudo selector that is created for you when using the widget factory.  `$(":namespace-widgetname")`

Answer (score 3):

@dan-story may have had the answer at the time he answered it, but I have found that that method doesn't work anymore. Well, not entirely.  At least not with jQueryUI 1.10. According to the documentation at http://api.jqueryui.com/jQuery.widget/ in the "Instance" section, you now need to have the widget's full name.

For example, if you create your widget factory with this:

```
$.widget("Boycs.investmentGrid", ...);
```

Then, to check if container has it, you would check with this:

```
if ($('#container').data('Boycs-investmentGrid'))
{
    ...
}
```

It is no longer enough to just use the name.

Answer (score 1):

@Boycs: As per my understanding, using Widget Factory protects you from instantiating a plugin multiple times on the same element. (ref: http://jqueryui.pbworks.com/widget-factory)

In addition if you want to confirm if "container" is already an investment grid you can try the following option from inside your plugin code:

> this.element.data("investmentGrid")
>   === this;

For more details you can refer to docs.jquery.com/UI_Developer_Guide

Comment: Thanks... 

I may not have been clear in my initial question... I need to be able to determine from outside of my plugin code whether or not $('#container') is already an investmentGrid or not...

Comment: Can you share with me why you would need to establish whether "container" is already an investmentGrid or not? It will help me answer more accurately. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Current versions of jQuery UI (I can confirm it with 1.11.x) allow you to query for an instance of a widget via the `instance()` method. This will then look like this:

```
$('#container').investmentGrid('instance')
```

If the element does not have an `investmentGrid` widget assigned, you will get `undefined` back.

You may also use call this instead:

```
$(#container').is(':data("namespace-investmentGrid")')
```

This has the advantage, that it also works even when the widget is not loaded.